# Session is closed when using using current_session_context_class = thread

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I'm using hibernate as ORM, and I have the following property in Hibernate config:

```
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Also I'm using the Generic Hibernate DAO lib: http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao

In my application (which is a Java EE web app) I'm having a background thread which runs continuously at regular intervals and picks up some data from a DB and stores it. So whenever some data comes in, we can show it to the user quickly.

Now the problem is it works only for the first time. When a thread runs for the first time it closes the session. When the background thread tries to fetch for a second time, the session is already closed so I get an error.

The generic DAO doesn't allow me to inject a session, but I can inject the session factory.
As the session factory picks a session using a thread property it gets a closed session the second time.

How can I solve this problem?

UPDATE:

Should i overide getCurrentSession() in  SessionFactoryImpl.java in following way?

so that it check is session is closed in currentSesioncontext if yes return a new session

Comment: What error are you getting? Post the code where you get and close off the session. The context is designed to allow a session to be opened the closed and dissociated.

Comment: Also see. stackoverflow.com/questions/10323133/how-to-reinitialize-session-in-hibernate-with-thread-context

Comment: @EdC saw the link.But how does calling rollback helps.And is it a good approach(i will check if it works and come back here)?Can u eleborate?

Comment: Do you start transaction before calling this DAO?

Comment: @EdC If i call rollback than then the session is never closed ,So what will happen is that the session will always be open and used by this background thread only .I think its  a problem as the background thread doesn not need it alway.Your comments plz